# Add new li inJcarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I have slider made in jcarousel. its working fine but i want to add new li with image onclick button . When i click button li and img adding succesfully but don't showing in slider.
Please help ..
this is my code

```
 function onImageClick(clicked_id,cls){
        var addLi="<li><img src=''  width=\"157px\" height=\"84px\" id='mainImg' /></li>";
        var $savedList = $("#mycarousel");
        $savedList.append(addLi);
        mycarousel_reloadCallback();

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the li into a ul - change the selector to

```
var $savedList = $("#mycarousel ul");
```

Comment: no i have try but it is also not working and giving error "e is null" in jquery.jcarousel.min.js file please give any suggestion..its urgent

Comment: Try removing the line 'mycarousel_reloadCallback();' - after clicking on the image, inspect your markup. Was the li added correctly inside the ul?

Comment: sorry dear not working. li and img is adding successfully but not running in slider if we remove 'mycarousel_reloadCallback();' then how can be reload

Comment: I'm trying to see if the markup has been correctly added first as I think this may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: markup has been going correctly i have checked with firebug its added new li.